# Error:Cannot invoke method systemProperty() on null object // New setup of Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I have installed Android Studio and linked it to my Gradle Project.

This is the first time I have set this up and then once I have installed  everything (plugins etc) i get the following error message in Message Gradle Sync:

**Gradle 'my-project' project refresh failed
    Error:Cannot invoke method systemProperty() on null object**

The event log shows:

**12:08 AM  Gradle sync failed: Cannot invoke method systemProperty() on null object
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)**

Please can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Project structure shows Gradle version 3.3
Android plugin version is blank (not sure if that is this is issue)

Could someone please tell me how I can resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Show us the `build.gradle` files.